# Auto/manually set column width JTable with db data

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In my code I have`JTable` filled with data from database.

This is constructor of my JPanel:

```
public MainPanel(Vector<Vector<String>> films) 
{
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int width = this.getSize().width;
    int height = this.getSize().height;
    int x = (dim.width-width)/2;
    int y = (dim.height-height)/2;

    header = new Vector<String>();
    data = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
    header.add("ID");
    header.add("Name");
    header.add("Year");
    header.add("Genre");
    this.data = films;

    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setLocation(x, y);
    initComponents();        
}
```

and this is initialize of `JTable`:

```
jTable2 = new javax.swing.JTable();

setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

jTable2.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        data, header
));

TableColumnModel tcm;
tcm = jTable2.getColumnModel();

for (int i = 0; i < header.size(); i++)
{
    TableColumn tc;
    tc = tcm.getColumn(i);
    tc.setWidth(2);
}
```

Can anybody help me why isn't width 2 and is same still?

Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 3):

Look into:

1. [`JTable.getColumnModel()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getColumnModel%28%29)
2. [`TableColumnModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumnModel.html)
3. [`TableColumnModel.getColumn(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumnModel.html#getColumn%28int%29)
4. [`TableColumn.setWidth(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumn.html#setWidth%28int%29) as well as the max/min variants.

Comment: but still not working :( ive edited my code as i've understood this methods

Answer (score 2):

See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Setting and Changing Column Widths](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#width). You are using the wrong method.

Answer (score 0):

Make your own table model by subclassing AbstractTableModel.
You can specify the row/column count, column names and cell values.
You will get a better understanding of the table model.